# How can I re-initialize a Docker container

Tags: docker, db2

I am using Docker to run a local instance of Db2 and mounting `~/` into the container as `/database` to create and store the database (`apidemo`).  The command is below.  It is working as expected and the database and data persists even as the container is stopped and restarted.

```
docker run -itd --name db2_container_inst -e DBNAME=apidemo -v ~/:/database -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=mY%tEst%pAsSwOrD -e LICENSE=accept -p 50000:50000 --privileged=true ibmcom/db2
```

My problem is that at times I need a clean, and empty, database, however, I can not seem to re-initialize the `docker run`.  I have tried deleting the container instance (`db2_container_inst`) using Docker Desktop, but when I re-run the command above, the database schema and data are the same as where I left off, it instead of an empty database.

Is there a way that I can re-initialize the container should I need to go back to an empty database?

Comment: You should be able to delete the host directory you mounted with `docker run -v`, or mount a different new empty directory.  (I probably wouldn't use your home directory for this.)

Comment: This is because your data are persisted on the mounting point `~` of your local machine. Just empty this folder of the db2 files, and you should be good when re-running the container.

Answer (score 3):

Under normal circumstances you would empty all the files from the host directory you mounted with two `rm -rf` - in your case

```
rm -rf ~/* # deletes all non-hidden files and directories
rm -rf ~/.* # deletes all hidden files and directories
```

However, since you mounted your **HOME** directory as a volume (*what possessed you to do that anyway?*) those command would break your user account, so you need to manually find and delete all the files created by your database container.

Once your done, please create an empty directory and use that as a bind mount:

```
mkdir ~/db_data
docker run -itd --name db2_container_inst -e DBNAME=apidemo -v ~/db_data:/database -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=mY%tEst%pAsSwOrD -e LICENSE=accept -p 50000:50000 --privileged=true ibmcom/db2
```

or better yet use named volume

```
docker volume create db_data
docker run -itd --name db2_container_inst -e DBNAME=apidemo -v db_data:/database -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=mY%tEst%pAsSwOrD -e LICENSE=accept -p 50000:50000 --privileged=true ibmcom/db2
```

Then if you need to clean the database you would remove your container and then run

```
rm -rf ~/db_data/*
rm -rf ~/db_data/.*
```

or

```
docker volume rm db_data
```

depending on which of the above methods you used to store the data in the first place.